# In mingw64, python scripts can't print() UTF-8 [Windows 10]

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, mingw, msys2

1. Install MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org/
2. Open the mingw64.exe terminal, and do the usual setup:

   ```
   pacman -Syu
   pacman -Su
   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3
   ```
3. Run a python script

   ```
   python3 test.py
   ```

The script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("가요대제전")
```

4. We get this traceback

```
$ python3 testme.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/home/user/testme.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("\uac00\uc694\ub300\uc81c\uc804")
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/encodings/cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Using `.encode()` resolves the traceback, but produces gibberish output:

```
print("가요대제전".encode("utf-8"))

b'\xea\xb0\x80\xec\x9a\x94\xeb\x8c\x80\xec\xa0\x9c\xec\xa0\x84'
```

Comment: The terminal appears to be configured to use the CP1252 encoding. I’m not familiar with the mingw64 terminal, but can you configure it for UTF8?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ideally, yes; but after much googling, I found only one semi-relevant result, https://en.anyquestion.info/a/step-by-step-how-to-set-up-mingw64-to-handle-utf-8-character-input, and it relies on a deleted Github repository.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
python3 -X utf8 test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your Python script is actually saved in UTF-8 encoding.

In Windows you can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to set UTF-8 encoding by opening the script and selecting "UTF-8" under the "Encoding" menu.

Then run it again with Python.

If you still get issues try setting the following environment variable:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

If you are in the MSYS shell you could try :

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 test.py
```